# desired effect using jquery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to get the effect of moving background image on a section like in below [website.](https://chipotle.com/)

Just about the footer when you scroll up and down the image behind "FIND A CHIPOTLE" scrolls and moves. I am not able to achieve the desired effect.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using CSS:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: They did it with the image as the body's background-image, so the `<section class="homepage-chipotle" data-language="en-us,en-ca">` just doesn't have a background.

Comment: yes thats what I found, so it confused me even more :P

Answer (score 0):

The body of the page has a background image. Most of the divs above it have a white background, but the one where you can see the image scrolling has "background: transparent;" which allows you to see the image attached to the page body. It's not the image itself that is scrolling but the divs above it.

Comment: And as HaehnleinMar said, the background image is 'fixed'